# why is <div> is behaving like a <br>? Should I use something else instead?

Tags: css, html

So I'm trying to practice making a website and I'm trying to have text centered between two pictures

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div style=" margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center;">
<p>poo</p></div>

<div "float:left; margin-top:-33px;">>
<img     src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-0kj0VRLro_o/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/8Aoyxk98YV0/s48-c-k/photo.jpg" width="297" height="241"/>
```

```
<div style="float:right; margin-top:-33px;">
<img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/HdqsNykr9cM/mqdefault.jpg" height="187">
 </div>
```

sorry about the weird spacing this is wat-tier forum-ing

Comment: Just specify **float:left** proerty to your DIV-s. --- still you have problem then use HTML TABLE. so SIMPLE...!

Comment: No! Ask yourself: is the data you're providing tabular? Is it a points table? No? Don't use a table. Never use tables for layouts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you use, `<span>` this will prevent you from `<div>` as `<br>`

Comment: No mate he got it, <div> was making a <br> between the different thingies. Switching it to <span> made it all centered and stuff

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are a few things wrong with your html markup:

- it's not well formed, you're missing a closing `</div>` tag
- you have inline styling without the `style` attribute, e.g. `<div "float:left; margin-top:-33px;">` should be `<div style="float:left; margin-top:-33px;">`
- `">>` is invalid html markup
- try not to use inline styling when possible.  Instead, create a separate stylesheet and use css classes.

I've created a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hsbRn/) where I've cleaned up your code a bit, and centered the text between the two images.  The general idea is to use `float: left` when you need elements to appear next to each other on the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do about what you want to do
The first one is to make a parent `div` with auto margins and then place your text and image `div`s in it and give `float:left` property to your text `div` and to both of your `img` tags like this:(if the direction of your parent `div` is the default left-to-right)

```
<div id="parent" style="margin: 0 auto 0">
    <div style="float:left"><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-0kj0VRLro_o/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/8Aoyxk98YV0/s48-c-k/photo.jpg" width="297" height="241</div>
    <div style="float:left;text-align:center"><p>poo</p></div> //this is your text div
    <div style="float:left"><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/HdqsNykr9cM/mqdefault.jpg" height="187"</div>
</div>
```

with this technic,you can correct the spacing between `div`s by giving the `div`s the desired margins.

the other thing you can do is to place all your `div`s in a parent `div`(just like what I showed above) but this time give the parent element a `display:relative` property and then give your child `div`s(the text and image `div`s) absolute positions (`position:absolute`) as you desire

(ps:I prefer the first answer I gave you!)